# SOLR, docValues=true, stored=true

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to SOLR. It is not clear to me why you would want to set stored=true when docValues is set to true as well?

SOLR can retrieve this value much faster using the docValues storage.
I think, when you set docValues=true, stored should be false to save storage?

Answer (score 1):

Firstable, docValues are not supported for all types, so this is already a full reason to use sort=true.

And secondable, retrieving a docvalues field is not always faster than retrieving a stored field.

docValues are specially valuable to speed up certain operations (facets, sorting...). Use them where needed, but keep stored=true if you need to as well.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for response, Obviously, where docValues are not supported, you would need stored=true. The documentation was stating that "if the retrieval is a mix of docValues and stored, docValues might create performance issues". So, as long as retrieval is only docValues, you might be better off with only docValues. So, base on my understand of the doc, I see stored=true only a good option when retrieval will be mixed. Thanks